# How to localize the title in add_menu_page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, localization

I have this code which I would like to localize for translation in the plugin I am building. Nothing on line seems to help. My own attempts return errors. Any help?

```
public function add_admin_pages() {
        //add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '' )
        add_submenu_page( 
            'woocommerce', 
            _e( 'Exporter réservations', 'export-bookings-to-csv' ),
            _e( 'Exporter réservations', 'export-bookings-to-csv' ), 
            'manage_options', 
            'export-bookings-to-csv', 
            array( $this,'export_bookings_to_csv') 
        );
    }
```

Comment: would be helpful, if you could show the error that you've mentioned

Comment: @igor-yavych I have added the error with the localization

Comment: I don't see the text of error anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are echoing the translation with `_e()`

You need to use `__()` to return the string.

```
public function add_admin_pages() {
    //add_submenu_page( string $parent_slug, string $page_title, string $menu_title, string $capability, string $menu_slug, callable $function = '' )
    add_submenu_page( 
        'woocommerce', 
        __( 'Exporter réservations', 'export-bookings-to-csv' ),
        __( 'Exporter réservations', 'export-bookings-to-csv' ), 
        'manage_options', 
        'export-bookings-to-csv', 
        array( $this,'export_bookings_to_csv') 
    );
}
```

You will find details when to use __() or _e() [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

```
$hello = __('Hello', 'txt-domain');
echo __('Hello', 'txt-domain');

echo $hello;
```

or using _e()

```
_e('Hello', 'txt-domain');
```

Comment: Could you help with this too?

$header = array( 'No Resas', 'Evenenements', 'Debut', 'Fin', 'Ressource', 'Nom', 'Prenom', 'Mail', 'Telephone', 'Prix paye');

Comment: _e() is always to display, when you want localization in a function or an array it's always __(),  for each word or sentence.

Comment: What is the error ? with wich action are you calling add_submenu_page() ?